# How to mark errors thrown by react axiosInterceptor as errors in swr useSWRMutation()?

Tags: reactjs, axios, swr

After checking the token in axios interceptor, throw an error if there is no token.

```
export const axiosInstance = (needAccess:boolean = true, needRefresh:boolean = false) => {
    const output = axios.create({
        baseURL : Env.BaseUrl
    })

    output.interceptors.request.use(
        (config) => {
            const tokenData = localStorage.getItem("token");
            if (needAccess) {
                if(tokenData == null){
                    throw new Error("토큰이 없습니다")
                }

                const token: Token = JSON.parse(tokenData)
                if(token.accessTokenExpiresAt.valueOf() < Date.now()){
                    throw new Error("토큰이 만료됬어요")
                }

                config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token.accessToken;
            }

            if (needRefresh) {
                if(tokenData == null){
                    throw new Error("토큰이 없습니다")
                }

                const token: Token = JSON.parse(tokenData)
                if(token.refreshTokenExpiresAt.valueOf() < Date.now()){
                    throw new Error("토큰이 만료됬어요")
                }

                config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token.refreshToken;
            }
            config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
            return config
        }
    )

    return output
}
```

' throw new Error("토큰이 만료됬어요") '
I throw an error like this, but I can't catch the error in useSWR

```
export class AuthRepositoryImplement implements AuthRepository {

    UserInfo():SWRMutationResponse<any, any, any, any>{
        const func = (url:string) => {
            return axiosInstance().get(url).then((data) => data.data,)
        }
        return useSWRMutation( "/auth/myInfo", func)
    }
}
```

I send a request, and get an error because there is no token, as expected, if(userInfoError){console.log(userInfoError)} should be executed, but
in the console window

I only get this error and the logic doesn't run, how can I get the logic to run?

```
axiosInit.tsx:15 Uncaught (in promise) Error: 토큰이 없습니다
    at axiosInit.tsx:15:27
    at async mutateByKey (index.mjs:324:20)
```

The code below is loginPage

```
const authRepository = new AuthRepositoryImplement()
export const LoginPage = () => {
    const {register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors },} = useForm<LoginData>()
    const {trigger: userLoginTrigger, isMutating, data:tokenData ,error: loginError} = authRepository.Login();
    const {trigger: userInfoTrigger,error: userInfoError} = authRepository.UserInfo();
    const [loginButtonString, setLoginButtonString] = useState("로그인")


    useEffect(() => {
        if(tokenData){
            setLoginButtonString("유저정보를 받아오는중...")
            userInfoTrigger().then(() => {
                if(userInfoError){
                    console.log(userInfoError)
                }
            })
        }
    },[tokenData, loginError])
```